# How to reuse Minitest support code in Cucumber step definitions?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cucumber, minitest

I have a test suite that uses Minitest. As per the Minitest docs, when I had common functionality, I extracted it into a module, then included that module into `ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest`, giving me access in my tests. In this case, the extracted functionality formatted the requests and parsed the responses in my integration tests.

Now, I'm bringing in Cucumber, but when I add `include MyHelperModule` in my steps definition file, it raises `NameError: undefined constant`.

*How can I include this functionality in my Cucumber step definitions without rewriting the module underneath `features/`?*

The module currently lives at `test/support/my_helper_module.rb`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `features/support/env.rb`, or in another `.rb` file in `features/support`, do

```
require_relative '../../test/support/my_helper_module'
```

`MyHelperModule` will then be available in step definitions.

Comment: To answer my meta-question, then, there is no built-in cucumber mechanism, but basic ruby mechanisms will work fine with no unexpected weirdness.